# Recycle view with variable widget size not working (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

So I have a program that receives a string from a server and formats it before adding it to a list used by a recycleview.  There is a function that is called when the texture size of one of the widgets in the list changes as they can be different sizes depending on the content.  However, whenever more items are added the recycleview goes completely wrong and all of the items overlap.

The behavior varies a lot so I cannot include every example of the issue but I have taken out the relevant code from my program and made a small example program which I will include below.  I have also added some images of the issue.

I have been unable to get this to work or find anyone with similar a similar issue.  Any help or links will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

example_string = 'test)£++£(0)+££+(test)£++£(0)+££+(test)£++£(0)+££+(test)£++£(0)+££+(test)£++£(0'

class MASTER(BoxLayout):
    def example_button(self, Button): # Demo of list updating
        global example_string # I know
        example_string += ')+££+(test)£++£(0'
        temp = []
        id_num = 0
        for post in example_string.split(')+££+('): # The string is an example of the input data
            temp.append({'message_id':id_num, 'text':('[font=Nunito-Bold.ttf][color=161616]Someone:[/color][/font]\n' + post.split(')£++£(')[0]), '_size':[0,0], '_group':str(id_num), '_score':int(post.split(')£++£(')[1])})
            id_num = id_num + 1
        App.get_running_app().posts = temp

class DemoApp(App):
    # One post format = {'message_id':0, 'text':'post_test_here','_size':[0,0], '_group':str(0), '_score':20}
    # Text fromat string = [font=Nunito-Bold.ttf][color=161616]Someone:[/color][/font]\n
    posts = ListProperty([{'message_id':0, 'text':'[font=Nunito-Bold.ttf][color=161616]Someone:[/color][/font]\nHello, this is a test of a post jhghjgjhgh','_size':[0,0], '_group':str(0), '_score':20}, {'message_id':1, 'text':'[font=Nunito-Bold.ttf][color=161616]Someone:[/color][/font]\nHello, this is a test of a post hghghghghghghg', '_size':[0,0], '_group':str(1), '_score':100}, {'message_id':2, 'text':'post_test_her\n\ne','_size':[0,0], '_group':str(2), '_score':20}])

    def update_message_size(self, message_id, texture_size):
        self.posts[message_id] = {**self.posts[message_id], '_size':[1, texture_size[1]]}
        print('Message ID = ' + str(message_id))
        print('Texture size = ' + str(texture_size))

    def up_vote(self, button, mode): # Not part of the problem
        if button.state == 'down':
            if mode == 'all':
                print("+1 upvote for message index:" + str(button.parent.parent.message_id) + ' in all posts')
            else:
                print("+1 upvote for message index:" + str(button.parent.parent.message_id) + ' in top posts')
    
    def down_vote(self, button, mode): # Not part of the problem
        if button.state == 'down':
            if mode == 'all':
                print("-1 upvote for message index:" + str(button.parent.parent.message_id) + ' in all posts')
            else:
                print("-1 upvote for message index:" + str(button.parent.parent.message_id) + ' in top posts')





if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

**demo.kv**

```
MASTER:

<MASTER>:
    Button:
        text: 'Add items'
        on_press: root.example_button(self)
    RecycleView:
        viewclass: 'PostGrid'
        scroll_y: 1
        id: rv
        data: app.posts
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            id: box
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: ["10dp", "16dp"]
            spacing: "20dp"
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            key_size: '_size'

<PostGrid@BoxLayout>:
    message_id: -1
    orientation: "horizontal"
    text: ''
    _group: ''
    _score: 0
    spacing: "6dp"
    text_size: None, None
    BoxLayout:
        id: voting_menu
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "2dp"
        size_hint: .2, 1
        size: self.size
        ToggleButton:
            id: button_up
            on_state: app.up_vote(self, 'all')
            group: str(root._group)
            text: "UP"
            color: (1,1,1,1) if self.state=='normal' else (.8,0,0,1)
            font_size: "10dp"
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_color: .2, .2, .2, 0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.1,.1,.1,1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [6,]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .2,.2,.2,1
                Line:
                    width: 1.4
                    rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
        Label:
            id: vote_count
            text: str(root._score)
            size_hint: 1, .4
            multiline: False

        ToggleButton:
            id: button_down
            on_state: app.down_vote(self, 'all')
            group: str(root._group)
            text: "DOWN"
            color: (1,1,1,1) if self.state=='normal' else (.8,0,0,1)
            font_size: "10dp"
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_color: .2, .2, .2, 0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.1,.1,.1,1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [6,]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.2,.2,.2,1)
                Line:
                    width: 1.4
                    rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
    Label:
        text: root.text
        padding: "10dp", "12dp"
        size_hint: .9, 1
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        font_size: "12dp"
        text_size: self.width, None
        color: 0,0,0,1
        multiline: True
        markup: True
        
        on_texture_size: app.update_message_size(root.message_id, self.texture_size)

        pos: self.pos

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.texture_size
                radius: [5, 5, 5, 5]
                pos: self.x, self.y
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:0.8,0,0,1
            Line:
                width: 1.4
                rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
```

**Image of unexpected behavior**
[image]
**Image of different unexpected behavior**
[image]
**Video of problem**
https://youtu.be/F_2TLh-cFYA

**Note**
I would encourage anyone to run this code to fully understand the problem since the code actually behaives as expected the first time I change what is stored in the list 'posts'

Comment: Not sure how to fix it, but I notice that your `update_message_size()` is only updating the first and last `PostGrid` instances. The ones in between have a `height` of `0`. That is causing the overlap.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yes, the thing that I really don't understand is that it consistently works the first time I change the items and then breaks.  It also fixes itself if I resize the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting `size` of the labels from inside instead of setting it from outside using `key_size`.

You might keep the `viewclass` widget of fixed height using the `minimum_height` and control its child widget by the label's texture height.

Thus your modified `PostGrid` and associated code in `kvlang` will look something like this,

```py
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            id: box
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            default_size: None, dp(50) #
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: ["10dp", "16dp"]
            spacing: "20dp"
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
#            key_size: '_size'
# Remove the associated prop. from python (i.e. from method 'example_button' etc.) as well.

<PostGrid@BoxLayout>:
    message_id: -1
    orientation: "horizontal"
    text: ''
    _group: ''
    _score: 0
    spacing: "6dp"
    text_size: None, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    BoxLayout:
        id: voting_menu
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "2dp"
        size_hint: .2, None
        height: label.height # This binding will force voting_menu to resize.
#        size: self.size # I don't think it has any effect.
        ToggleButton:
            id: button_up
            on_state: app.up_vote(self, 'all')
            group: str(root._group)
            text: "UP"
            color: (1,1,1,1) if self.state=='normal' else (.8,0,0,1)
            font_size: "10dp"
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_color: .2, .2, .2, 0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.1,.1,.1,1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [6,]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .2,.2,.2,1
                Line:
                    width: 1.4
                    rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
        Label:
            id: vote_count
            text: str(root._score)
            size_hint: 1, .4
            multiline: False

        ToggleButton:
            id: button_down
            on_state: app.down_vote(self, 'all')
            group: str(root._group)
            text: "DOWN"
            color: (1,1,1,1) if self.state=='normal' else (.8,0,0,1)
            font_size: "10dp"
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_color: .2, .2, .2, 0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.1,.1,.1,1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [6,]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.2,.2,.2,1)
                Line:
                    width: 1.4
                    rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
    Label:
        id: label # For reference.
        text: root.text
        padding: "10dp", "12dp"
        size_hint: .9, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        font_size: "12dp"
        text_size: self.width, None
        color: 0,0,0,1
        multiline: True
        markup: True
        
#        on_texture_size: app.update_message_size(root.message_id, self.texture_size)

#        pos: self.pos

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.texture_size
                radius: [5, 5, 5, 5]
                pos: self.x, self.y
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:0.8,0,0,1
            Line:
                width: 1.4
                rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
```

Comment: Hi ApuCoder, you have helped me massively in the past. I have to go out now but thank you very much for your answer and I look forward to trying it out when I get back :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly.  I also appreciate the other more minor tweaks, I will use them in the future.

Comment: After some more time to test this it seems like it suffers from a similar issue to before just to a lesser extent.  Sometimes it works perfectly but a lot of the time the items still overlap or are in the wrong place.  Is there any way to slow down how fast it attempt to resize the widgets?

Comment: Yes, you may also notice an unexpected variable amount of space inbetween. In my experience `RecycleView ` works better with fixed `height`. For variable height, apart from this implementation, perhaps you may need to precompute the heights and update the contents each time. However if I find a better way, I'll update the answer.

Comment: In terms of resizing your solution worked perfectly, which I imagine has brought me closer to the solution.  As of now, the only issue I can find is that the items appear in the wrong places which causes them to overlap.  Also thanks again for your time

Comment: You may try with `ScrollView` inside your viewclass `PostGrid`. That will keep the height fixed but with no other issue, I think.

Comment: Will using scrollview not make the program very slow when updating 100+ items?

Comment: I don't think so, there might be other kind of problems though. In case you didn't notice, I said `ScrollView` inside your viewclass.

Comment: I have found a solution, I will upload it soon (However the buttons still need some work)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively<sup>**#**</sup> you can use `ScrollView` to scroll over the extended labels. But here each of your `viewclass` widget will have same height. Also due to the presence of `ScrollView` in inner widget you have to either scroll the widgets from one side (which is quite common) or manipulate the touch dispatching event yourself depending on `scroll_y` value.

```py
MASTER:

<MASTER>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.15
        text: 'Add items'
        on_press: root.example_button(self)
    RecycleView:
        viewclass: 'PostGrid'
        scroll_y: 1
        id: rv
        data: app.posts
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            id: box
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            default_size: None, dp(64) # Specify it explicitly. Adjust to your need.
            size_hint_y: None
            padding: ["10dp", "16dp"]
            spacing: "20dp"
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'


<PostGrid@BoxLayout>:
    message_id: -1
    orientation: "horizontal"
    text: ''
    _group: ''
    _score: 0
    spacing: "6dp"
    text_size: None, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: dp(100) # Adjust to your need.
    BoxLayout:
        id: voting_menu
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "2dp"
        size_hint_x: 0.2
        ToggleButton:
            id: button_up
            on_state: app.up_vote(self, 'all')
            group: str(root._group)
            text: "UP"
            color: (1,1,1,1) if self.state=='normal' else (.8,0,0,1)
            font_size: "10dp"
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_color: .2, .2, .2, 0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.1,.1,.1,1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [6,]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: .2,.2,.2,1
                Line:
                    width: 1.4
                    rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
        Label:
            id: vote_count
            text: str(root._score)
            size_hint: 1, .4
            multiline: False

        ToggleButton:
            id: button_down
            on_state: app.down_vote(self, 'all')
            group: str(root._group)
            text: "DOWN"
            color: (1,1,1,1) if self.state=='normal' else (.8,0,0,1)
            font_size: "10dp"
            size_hint: 1, .3
            background_color: .2, .2, .2, 0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.1,.1,.1,1)
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    radius: [6,]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.2,.2,.2,1)
                Line:
                    width: 1.4
                    rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
    ScrollView:
        effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.size
                radius: [5, 5, 5, 5]
                pos: self.pos
            Color:
                rgba:0.8,0,0,1
            Line:
                width: 1.4
                rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
        
        Label:
            text: root.text
            padding: "10dp", "12dp"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            font_size: "12dp"
            text_size: self.width, None
            color: 0,0,0,1
            multiline: True
            markup: True
```

---

**#** This is in response to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456569/recycle-view-with-variable-widget-size-not-working-kivy/71525420#comment126341735_71459040).

Comment: I will give this a test, thank you very much